# Checking UITextInteractionAssistant class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to control gesture recognizer in my view like this.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    NSMutableArray *targets = [gestureRecognizer valueForKeyPath:@"_targets"];
    id targetContainer = targets[0];//get first target for example
    id targetOfMyGes = [targetContainer valueForKeyPath:@"_target"];

    NSMutableArray *targets1 = [otherGestureRecognizer valueForKeyPath:@"_targets"];
    id targetContainer1 = targets1[0];//get first target for example
    id targetOfOtherGes = [targetContainer1 valueForKeyPath:@"_target"];

    if ([targetOfMyGes isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]] || [targetOfOtherGes isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]])
    {

    }

}
```

When I debug, targetOfOtherGes is like this.

```
(lldb) po targetOfOtherGes
<UITextInteractionAssistant: 0x194afdd0>
```

I need to check whether targetOfOtherGes is class of UITextInteractionAssistant. However, when I check, I got error like this. It say forward declaration. So, I need to import .h file. But, which file shall I import?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's [part of UIKit](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UITextInteractionAssistant.h). If it isn't showing up as valid then it's probably because Apple doesn't want you to have access to it.

It's kind of janky, but I've gotten around a similar problem with `UISegment` by doing something like this:

```
// the class definition in some header
@interface FakeSegment : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) id label;

@end

// how the fake definition can be used to get what you want
NSString* typeName = NSStringFromClass([segment class]);
if ([typeName isEqualToString:@"UISegment"]) {
    UILabel *label = ((FakeSegment *)segment).label;
}
```